# How to send coordinates to SQL server every 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to send GPS coordinates to a server from an HTML/PHP webpage at an interval of every. 3 seconds. How would I go about sending this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will collect the coordinates of the browser every 3 seconds and send to a file called processor.php with GET parameters, lat and lon. Place this before the closing body tag on your HTML page:

```
<script>
function sendRequest(position) {
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         setTimeout(function() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sendRequest);
         }, 3000);
      }
   };
   req.open('GET', 'processor.php?lat='+position.coords.latitude+'&lon='+position.coords.longitude, true);
   req.send();
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sendRequest);
</script>
```

Place this PHP code in processor.php:

```
<?php
$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$lon = $_GET['lon'];

//update SQL database as necessary with above variables
?>
```